# I need to be able to a) use virtual hosts in my home folder on Linux, and b) use symlinks

Tags: wordpress, apache, apache2, symlink

So I have Ubuntu 12.04 (Desktop) and want to setup a virtual host for `a.localhost`. I know how to setup the `sites-enabled` and `/etc/hosts`. What I haven't been able to figure out is how to direct the virtual hosts to `/home/aubrey/a.project` and link `/home/aubrey/a.project/b` to `/home/aubrey/Project A/b` and be able to access it all using `http://a.localhost/b`

Another Explanation:

Ironically, I did this just fine on Windowz and xampp. I just want to be able to keep plugin code in repositories in my home folder and a WordPress install in something like `/home/aubrey/a-wordpress` and have `/home/plugin-project/plugin-a` linked to `/home/aubrey/a-wordpress/wp-content/plugins/plugin-a`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this problem apply to all files within the plugins directory? Specifically static files like CSS or JS? Or does this problem only occur with PHP files?

If it's only the PHP files, check your PHP configuration. Maybe you have an `open_basedir` configured there?

Comment: I have a plugins file in /home/a.project/plugins and want to symbolically link that to /home/vhosts/a.project/wp-content/plugins - not a php issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you want `+SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`, not `-SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`. The - says to disallow the directive as opposed to the + which turns the directive on. But it's definitely possible that something else is going to cause problems here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is what I did to get things working:

First, enabled userdir

`sudo a2enmod userdir`

Then, edited `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    # To re-enable php in user directories comment the following lines
    # (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
    # prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        <Directory /home/*/public_html>
            #php_admin_value engine Off
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Notice I commented out the `php_admin_value` to allow PHP.

Then, created a virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName philknight.localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/aubrey/public_html/philknight-wordpress
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/aubrey/public_html/philknight-wordpress>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And, in `/home/aubrey/public_html/philknight-wordpress` was able to create a link to `wp-content` elsewhere in my home folder, `/home/aubrey/Documents/Projects & Companies/Excion/Metz Tennis/PhilKnight/wp-content/themes/philknight` to be exact actually. I used the common `SHIFT_CTRL` drag method, but I'm sure `ln -s` would work too.

Hope this helps anyone, comment if you have questions...

Permissions:

`drwxrwxrwx  4 www-data www-data  4096 Aug 20 18:46 /home/aubrey/public_html`

`drwxrwxrwx 8 aubrey aubrey    4096 Aug 20 21:11 /home/aubrey/Documents/Projects & Companies/Excion/Metz Tennis/PhilKnight/wp-content`

Also had to `chmod 777 -R /home/aubrey/Documents/Projects & Companies/Excion/Metz Tennis/PhilKnight/wp-content/plugins` and `/home/aubrey/Documents/Projects & Companies/Excion/Metz Tennis/PhilKnight/wp-content/themes`